# My Fragment layout is overlapping Activity layout

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an `Activity` with two buttons. `Button` click opens a new `Fragment`. But the `Fragment` view is overlapping my `Activity` view.

**I have tried giving background to my fragment but it is not working for me**

[image: Activity with 2 buttons]

[image: Fragment for Schedule Match Match]

**Here is activity xml code**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#E6E6E6"
    tools:context=".TourAdmin">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tour_admin_tour_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="Tournament Name"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/tour_admin_schedule"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tour_admin_tour_name"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="Schedule Match"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/tour_admin_show_for_score"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tour_admin_schedule"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="Score Match"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/admin_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Here is fragment xml code:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    tools:context=".TourScheduleMatch">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/tour_team1_select_spinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                android:paddingRight="6dp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/tour_team2_select_spinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tour_team1_select_spinner"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                android:paddingRight="6dp"
                />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/tour_sched_half_time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tour_team2_select_spinner"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                android:paddingRight="6dp"
                android:entries="@array/match_time"/>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/tour_sched_nop"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tour_sched_half_time"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                android:paddingRight="6dp"
                android:entries="@array/tournament_nop"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/tour_cityNameEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:hint="City"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/tour_sched_nop"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/tour_groundNameEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:hint="Ground"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/tour_cityNameEditText"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/match_date_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/tour_groundNameEditText"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/tour_match_date_bn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                    android:paddingRight="6dp"
                    android:text="Match Date"
                    android:textColor="#fff" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tour_match_date"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
                    android:text="Match Date"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/match_time_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/match_date_layout"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/tour_match_time_bn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                    android:paddingRight="6dp"
                    android:text="Match Time"
                    android:textColor="#fff" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tour_match_time"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
                    android:text="Match Time"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tour_schedule_schedule_bn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/match_time_layout"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:text="Create"
                android:textColor="#fff" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post here your .xml file content

Comment: @DawidJamroży I have posted the content

Comment: @Anmol IDK, does it matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using RelativeLayout here is wrong option. You should use LinearLayout instead. Place your FrameLayout as first view in your activity layout and change its visibility from gone to visible when needed.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="#E6E6E6"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/admin_fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tour_admin_tour_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:text="Tournament Name"
    android:textSize="30dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/tour_admin_schedule"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:text="Schedule Match"
    android:textColor="#fff" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/tour_admin_show_for_score"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tour_admin_schedule"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:text="Score Match"
    android:textColor="#fff" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Another option is using ConstraintLayout but it is harder to use than LinearLayout.

Comment: I tried this, it just loads the fragment below the buttons, I want it to open in as new screen

Comment: It can't load fragment below buttons because this is `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation and `FrameLayout` is placed above your other views. Settings `FrameLayout` visibility to visibile will make it height to full screen. If it loaded fragment below button, You did something wrong.

Another options is to use Activity with single `FrameLayout` and two fragments which will be swapping each other in `FrameLayout` place.

Comment: It is working, actually i had put `FrameLayout` below the button so it was loading below. But if i come back to my activity, how do i make it gone again?

Comment: Just set `FrameLayout` visibility to `GONE`.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are using a ConstraintLayout. To make the elements align one after another, use a LinearLayout or FrameLayout.

Comment: No, I'm using relative layout.

Comment: It's the same behaviour in Relative view as well. Might be you would have used alignParentTop as true for your fragment.

Comment: Try to create a structure like this.

<ScrollView>
     <LinearLayout>
            // Your Views
     </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

Comment: Same issue bro i tried : <ScrollView> <LinearLayout> // Your Views </LinearLayout> </ScrollView> but it still ovelaps :(

Comment: You have used RelativeLayout.